# How to get search terms / keywords only for a specific page?

Tags: google-analytics

Users visit a specific page on my website. I need to display all search terms / keywords that brought them to this page.

I [read here](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/analytics/Dac4FvRVvqU/crAHGVW60LEJ), that this should work:

> 1. Top Content > Do a regex search for /yoursite/.
> 2. Once you found the content (page) you want drill down to it which will display the Content Detail report. Now dimension it by Source.
>      Now this is simply going to shoot out all the traffic sources (Direct, Referring Sites, SE's & Not Set). From this list, what we really want is the SE's you recognise.
> 3. Now dimension again for the second time by Keyword.

But it does not seem to work. Or it works and I don't have any keyword for the specific page?

Can somebody help out?

Comment: This probably would do better on [webmasters.se] rather than here.

Comment: As far as I can recall I posted this question originally in superuser.com

Comment: You did, and five people there thought it would be better here. I disagree with them. Google Analytics questions seem to do better at Webmasters.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom report with the URL you are interested in.

In **Report Content**, add **Pageviews** to the Metric Group and **Keyword** to the Dimension Drilldown

In **Filters**, add "Include **Page** Exact **/path/to/page.html**"

Like so:

[image: GA custom report edit & resul]

This shows the edit screen and results.